# Cómo registrar datos actualizados de una tabla en otra tabla SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Bendiciones
La presente es para saber si alguien puede ayudarme con esta inquietud. A continuación explico en detalle:

Me gustaría saber cómo guardar correctamente en una tabla los registros antes de actualizarse y actualizados de otra tabla

Yo lo he hecho con un trigger de una manera, pero registra todos los registros sin filtrarlo, es decir que guarda **todos** los registros que estaban antes de actualizar y los que se quedaron en la tabla actualizada

Entonces no es correcto. Lo que necesito guardar esos cambios solo del registro específico que se actualizó.

Un ejemplo del trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_UpdateNew
   ON  Users
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @user_id INT
DECLARE @Name_Old varchar(100)
DECLARE @Name_New varchar(100)

--valores antes de actualizar 
Select @user_id=user_id, @Name_Old= Name
From deleted

--valores nuevos
Select @Name_New= Name
From inserted

Insert into tbl_UsersUpdated
(user_id, Name_Old, Name_New)
values
(@user_id, @Name_Old, @Name_New)
END
GO
```

Después de actualizar un registro en particular de las tabla users, entonces el trigger se dispara, pero registra en la tabla `tbl_UsersUpdated` todos los registros existentes users.

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que los *trigger* se disparan por instrucción (p. ej. `update ...`), no por registro. Si haces algo como `update User set Name = upper(Name) where user_id < 100;`, aunque afecte a 50 registros solo se lanzará el *trigger* **una** vez, por tanto lo de asignar variables locales no es operativo de la forma que lo planteas. Para tu ejemplo, se podría hacer algo así:

```
CREATE Trigger TR_UpdateNew on Users for update as
begin
    insert into tbl_UsersUpdated (
          user_id
        , Name_Old
        , Name_New
        )
    select i.user_id
        ,  d.Name
        ,  i.Name
    from INSERTED i, DELETED d
    where i.user_id = d.user_id
end
```

Comment: Hola Xabi, Muchísimas gracias por tu apoyo!!! Era lo que buscaba. Lo probé y funcionó correctamente. Gracias millllllllllll.